# Custom menu tags in wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to get the function wp_nav_menu() to output the following html structure:

```html
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li><span>element</span>
 <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li><span>element</span>
 <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li><!--no element HERE!-->
</ul>
```

I tried with parameters like 'after' and 'link_after'. But the first one outputs the element before `</li>` tag and the next one before `</a>` tag. Is there any way to output the `<span>` element after `</li>` tags?
I read about the Walker class but I don't quite understand its logic - I'm not that good at PHP.

Comment: Why would you want to add a `<span>` outside of the `<li>`? It's invalid HTML...

Comment: I try to integrate an html template with wordpress. The html file I admit is poorly written but it works fine. The span element serves as a sort of division line between menu elements. My job is to make sure it works well with wordpress rather than produce a valid code. The best idea would be of course to insert pseudo :after element via css or give border-right to list elements but it doesn't work smoothly. I don't have time to experiment so I'd rather use semantically wrong code which at least looks fine in a browser.

Comment: Using an invalid HTML which looks fine often means it looks fine only for your browser, settings etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have no wp installed to test it, but still leave it here.
You need to extend the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class, like this:

```
class custom_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu 
{
    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $output .= "</li><span>element</span>\n";
    }
}
```

And then pass `new custom_walker_nav_menu` as `$walker` parameter for `wp_nav_menu()` function.
Actually, this answer is uncomplete, can't get how to get rid off last `<span>` element you don't need. I'll try to improve it later. Also as @ rnevius mentioned in his comment it would be an invalid HTML, so you should definately use one of `after` or `link_after`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it right away. In the meantime...here's what I need to output: http://klimat-test.ct8.pl/. It's acctually a div element which doesn't make it less wrong:P

Comment: And still, why don't you keep all stuff like <a> and <span> inside the <li> tag?

Comment: For some reason my css didn't work while in wordpress when I put this div inside <li> tag. The verticval lines would just disappear. I didn't bother to check why but I guess you're right that maybe the simplest solution is the best

Comment: That's for sure, check the KISS principle for coding. And if you want to keep your vertical lines - try and play with <a> or <li> css border properties.

Comment: I think I'll go with your advice of border properites. Moving <div> inside <li> elements breaks the layout. It looks like this: http://klimat-test.ct8.pl/glowna.html
I'm too tired to look for a reason:P